# AWS http connection timed out (Public DNS doesn`t work)

Tags: amazon-web-services, key, key-pair

Long story short: I had to change the .pem certificate so I created a new temporary instance with new certificate, switched the volume to change the certificate with the new one, removed the temporary instance, attached the volume back to the main instance as primary volume.
Now I have no issues connecting to the old(main) instance with the new certificate (SSH) but unfortunately the public DNS doesn`t work anymore.
The Security Group is exactly the same as before, both 80 and 443 ports are open for incoming (same with port 22). Any idea what might be the issue?

Asked on Amazon Forum aswell but no answer...

Comment: Of course I'm talking about AWS EC2

Comment: Its not possible SSH is working and DNS(Public IPv4)  is not working because in SSH also used port 22 of same DNS.

Comment: It is possible. You can find many posts like mine.

Comment: When you stop and then start an EC2 instance the public IP address can and often does change. This will change your DNS name. Public IP addresses are not persistent. If you need a static IP address assign an Elastic IP Address (EIP) to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the public IP of the instance and the A record of the DNS entry against the domain name? Are they same?

As you have created a new instance and presuming that you have not used Elastic IP, the new instance would have gotten a new IP which might not be matching the IP present as the A record against the Domain Name. You can run command

```
dig  <domain name>
```

and match it against

```
curl checkip.amazonaws.com
```

on that instance.

Could you please mention the forum link so that I could have a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi S Square. Thanks for your reply. Going to check. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=272795

Comment: doesn`t help. after digging further into it looks like even though security group accepts port 80, the server is not listening to that port

Comment: Please provide the output of the following command:
`$ netstat -tlpn` 
and check if there is a listener on port 80 
Also, check if there is an issue with the server application (apache/nginx)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the firewall blocked everything and made issues. It's configuration was changed but I don't know why.